if(fork()) and if(!fork()) - how do they work?
Let's say we have the following:
pid_t pid;
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) {
        if(fork()) printf("A");
        else printf("B");
        printf("C");
}
else {
        if(!fork()) printf("A");
        else if (fork()) printf("B");
        else printf("C");
}
    

How many A's, B's and C's are going to be printed?
I'm a little bit confused with how fork() works inside "if" and whether I'm in parent or child process.

'I'm a little bit confused', OK, so why use a construct that is confusing, given an obvious alternative?

It's actually an exercise I have to solve given the code above

The if branch is followed if the condition compares equal to 0, otherwise the else branch (if any) is followed. The ! operator produces 1 if its operand compares equal to 0, otherwise it produces 1. The fork() function creates a child process that is mostly a copy of the calling (parent) process. fork() returns from the calling (parent) process with the non-zero PID of the newly created child process, and returns from the newly created child process with the value 0. With that information, you should be able to determine how many As, Bs, and Cs are printed.

"How many A's, B's and C's are going to be printed?" - There is no way to tell since the whole program may terminate after B in the starting process is printed since there's no wait/waitpid. It'd be a different story if the last line was while(wait(NULL) != -1) {}

@TedLyngmo Wouldn't the child processes continue executing when the parent exits?

@Ted Lyngmo, In of itself, a process exiting doesn't kill its children. The reason child/background processes die is usually from a terminal closing (SIGHUP) or a broken pipe (SIGPIPE). That's not relevant here.

For debugging multiprocess code like this, I like to make sure that the printf() statements identify the process doing the writing and ensure that the format strings end with a newline — printf("%d: A\n", getpid());.  That makes an assumption that the pid_t type is not larger than int; I've yet to meet a system where that is not the case.  Since the code prints A's, B's and C's in different parts, I'd probably also arrange to print the source code line number or change the string from "A" to "A1" or "A2" to disambiguate which output came from where.

@interjay Sometimes they will, sometimes they won't. To get a consistant behavior, I would add waits.

@ikegami I think it is relevant since it makes the number of characters one will see in different situations different, even in different runs in the same environment, without waits

Beware of what happens when you don't include newlines in the output — see printf() anomaly after fork().

@Ted Lyngmo, No it won't. Waiting has no effect. The children will run and print whatever they will print whether you wait for them to finish or not. Again, a process exiting has no effect on its children. (Ok, it has one. Their parent parent process becomes init. This has no effect on what they print, though.)

@ikegami Depending in what environment the program is run and also depending on how I compile it, I get from 1 to 7 letters output. Take a containerized env. that shuts down when the started program exits for example. I often got 4-5 chars but a few times just the B. Adding wait makes it consistant.

@Ted Lyngmo, You're getting less data because you're not letting the application complete. That's on you. By your logic, printf("a\n"); printf("b\n"); could print nothing, a or a and b. True, but nonsense. There's an implied "if you let the application complete in the question".

@ikegami You are making assumptions about the environment that I prefer to not make. The possible outcomes I mention are not far fetched but actually very real if you deploy the program in different VMs or even freestanding environments.

@Ted Lyngmo, No I'm not. I'm assuming that external events (like power failures and the like) are unrelated to the question. You should be assuming the same, but you're assuming the opposite. You're assumes that something external (unrelated to the program) happens before the program finishes running. That's not relevant. The program always outputs the same thing regardless of environment unless something external terminates it. Noone would say that printf("a\n"); printf("b\n"); sometimes only print a. You shouldn't either.

@ikegami You are confusing statement I've made. I am not making the twisted argument you've tried to subscribe me to (now twice)

@Ted Lyngmo You suggested the program might not output everything if you terminate it prematurely. Container exiting was your example of an external force terminating the program. That would equally affect the OP's program and printf("a\n"); printf("b\n");.  Feel free to correct yourself if you misspoke.

@ikegami Re: "Take a containerized env. that shuts down when the started program exits for example" and "By your logic, printf("a\n"); printf("b\n"); could print nothing" - No, your interpretation of what I wrote is wrong. See it as waitpid(pid_of_started_program,...); shutdown();

@Ted Lyngmo, That's an example of an external force killing the program, just like I said. If you include those, one would have to claim that printf("a\n"); printf("b\n"); could print nothing at all. It's ridiculous to include those. Things like container exiting, terminal closing and power outages are not relevant here.

@ikegami The difference between the two is that people are likely to deploy their programs in an environment like what I described sooner or later. It's not uncommon for online IDEs to exhibit that behavior for example. I have never seen an environment behaving like what you describe.

@Ted Lyngmo, Re "I have never seen an environment behaving like what you describe.", I didn't describe any environment??? (Or I described every environment, depending on how you look at it.)

@ikegami Yes, the one in which "one would have to claim that printf("a\n"); printf("b\n"); could print nothing at all" - which is very different from the environment I've described

@Ted Lyngmo, That can happen in every environment, including the one you described

@ikegami The type of environment I describe behaves constantly so. It's not because someone pulls the plug or anything similar.

@Ted Lyngmo, Re "It's not because someone pulls the plug or anything similar.", uh, yes it is. That's exactly what happens in the scenario you described. The reason the output is incomplete in your scenario is because the container script pulls the plug on the VM running the program before the program is done running. Sure, it happens automatically because the container script is poorly written, but the entire machine being shut down is still the reason the output is truncated. You said it yourself. "Take a containerized env. that shuts down".

@ikegami "the container script is poorly written" - If the contract is that it will wait for the started program before it shuts down, it does exactly that. If the started program clones itself, then the clones will for sure not be waited for. It doesn't mean it's poorly written but that it does what it's meant to do.

@Ted Lyngmo, Powering the machine off while the program is still running is what it's supposed to do? Don't be ridiculous.

@ikegami "what it's supposed to do" -  I adapt to reality.


I'm a little bit confused with how fork() works inside "if" and whether I'm in parent or child process.

fork() works the same way inside an if condition as it does anywhere else.  It causes a duplicate of the current process to be created, and returns in both processes.  In the child, the return value is 0, which is falsey, whereas in the parent (on success) it returns the child's pid, which is non-zero and therefore truthy.
Thus with ...

if(fork()) printf("A");
        else printf("B");


... for example, the printf("A") branch is taken in the parent, where fork() returned a truthy value, and the else printf("B") branch is taken in the child (supposing that the fork succeeds) where fork() returned 0.
It is not necessary to store the return value of fork(), or any other function in a variable.  It can be used directly, which is not particularly uncommon, or it can even be ignored altogether, which also is not uncommon.
I leave it to you to work out the actual solution to the exercise.

The outputs may differ depending on the way the processes are executed by your machine but the concept is that when you use if(fork()){//block} you're basically creating a new child process and only allowing the parent process to access the block of code inside the if statement since for the child process the fork() returns 0 which is false and for the parent it returns the child PID which is != 0 meaning it's 'true', similarly the if(!fork()){//block} does the opposite and only allows the child process to enter the block of code. The output will consist of a combination of A, B, and C printed by different processes. The exact order depends on the scheduling of the processes.

First, the mandatory reminder:
The fork() system call returns:

Child process: 0
Parent process: PID of child process

Below is your code, indented, and with comments about process per line :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    /* P1 = parent */
    pid = fork();                                 /* P1 creates P2 */
    if(pid == 0) {                                /* P2 */
        if(fork())                                /* P2 creates P3, P2 branch  */
            printf("A");                          /* P2 */
        else                                      /* P3 */
            printf("B");                          /* P3 */
        printf("C");                              /* P2 and P3 */
    } else {                                      /* P1 */
        if(!fork())                               /* P1 creates P4, P4 branch */
            printf("A");                          /* P4 */
        else                                      /* P1 */
            if (fork())                           /* P1 creates P5, P1 branch */
                printf("B");                      /* P1 */
            else                                  /* P5 */
                printf("C");                      /* P5 */
    }
                                                  /* P1, P2, P3, P4, P5 */
}

The process tree with their output is:
                      P1 (B)
                      |
         ---------------------------
         |            |            |
         P2 (A + C)   P4 (A)       P5 (C)
         |
         P3 (B + C)

Note that for each process, the order of output is as written above
(for example, P2 will print A then C). But output between processes is
unknown, they could be in any order (for example A(P2) then B(P1) then C(P5)
then C(P2), etc...).
About processes, we know that P1 creates P2, P4, P5 in this order, but P3,
created by P2, can effectively be created before P4, between P4 and P5, or after P5.
